# How can I configure vim so that movement commands will include underscores and CamelCase, but completion will ignore them?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

For example, I currently have this:

```
set iskeyword-=_
```

This has the effect of making this work:

```
foo_bar
```

If cursor is on "f", pressing w moves cursor to the underscore.  Pressing again moves to the  "b" in bar.  This is the desired effect for movement, but has the undesired side-effect of breaking completion.  Same story with CamelCase tokens.  For example,

If I have this:

```
foo_bar
```

and I type `foo_<CTRL+N>` I don't get "foo_bar" as a completion option.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Install the [camelcase motion plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) and follow the example on the page to override the default `w` mapping with the CamelCase one.  This will make movements follow CamelCase, but won't require changes to `iskeyword`.  Alternatively you can use the alternative comma-preceded mappings (my preference), `,w`, `,e` etc to do CamelCase motions.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I kept the original wbe motions, though.  +1 for also fixing CamelCase, which wasn't part of my original question :)