# Can vim delete words within variable names?

Tags: vim

If I have a variable/function name called SqlDatabaseConnection, and I put my cursor on the first "S", is there a way to delete the "words" as defined by the uppercase letters ("Sql" and "Database")?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279462/how-can-i-configure-vim-so-that-movement-commands-will-include-underscores-and-ca

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you could use [camelcasemotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) plugin as a move command in your deletion (`d,w`). For the record, I'd use `dtD` or `dtC`.

Comment: It looks like that plugin also provides "inner word" analogs, so you could delete one segment of a camelcase name without even having the cursor on the end of it!

Comment: Also like the dtD trick, I was trying to do dfD before, which obviously didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

This can work (*delete till*):

```
dt<letter>
```

So, in your example *dtD* will delete "Sql".

Another variation:

```
d/[A-Z]
```

You can repeat delete by pressing "."

Answer (score 1):

As icecrime said, camelcasemotion plugin does this exactly.

If you don't want to install a plugin, you can create a macro like that :

> qc
>
> v
>
> /[A-Z]\|\</e-1
>
> (*press ENTER*)
>
> x
>
> q

I split the different part of the macro, but you have to type these without spaces nor carriage return, except the (*press Enter*) part which just means you should press enter at this step of the macro creation.

After that, just put the cursor on the first letter of the camelcase variable, and @c will delete words one by one the Camel way.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.  I generally count or estimate the number of letters I want to delete and use 'nx' where n is the number of letters to delete.