# Adding new word boundry movement macros in vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to change the word boundaries to make it more specific to your programming language or naming convention? And then, define a new macro while keeping the basic movements like w,W,b,B etc.?

For example:
`Class.method_name` would would not recognize the underscore as a word break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [How can I configure vim so that movement commands will include underscores and CamelCase, but completion will ignore them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279462/how-can-i-configure-vim-so-that-movement-commands-will-include-underscores-and-ca)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

In your example, `:set iskeyword-=_` will recognise the underscore as a word-break.

See `:help 'iskeyword'` for more information.