# Changing parts of CamelCase words in vim

Tags: vim, camelcasing

Using vim, I find `cw` very handy for changing an entire word.  Vim's separation of motion commands and action verbs makes for very powerful combinations.  I just now had to change `DefaultHandler` to `ContentHandler`.  I naturally thought of it as "change up to the next uppercase letter", but I couldn't find a motion command that moved from one uppercase letter to the next.

In this case, I could have used `ctH`, but is there a way to change (or delete, etc) the first part of a CamelCase word regardless of which uppercase letter comes next?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I configure vim so that movement commands will include underscores and CamelCase, but completion will ignore them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279462/how-can-i-configure-vim-so-that-movement-commands-will-include-underscores-and-c) (as mentioned in Luc's answer, which I think should be a comment)

Answer (score 5):

Vim doesn't provides a CamelCase word text object by default, so we'll have to 
create it by ourselves. The good new is that we don't need to reinvent the wheel
since a plugin already exists and we can use it as a base: [camelCaseMotion](https://github.com/bkad/CamelCaseMotion)

This script defines motions `,w`, `,b` and `,e` (similar to `w`, `b`, `e`), which do not move word-wise (forward/backward), but Camel-wise; i.e. to word boundaries and uppercase letters. The problem is that it doesn't
define a text object similar to `iw` to select an entire word. So let's create
it:

To be complete, a text object need two definitions: one for the visual mode and
another one for the operator pending mode. Here are our definitions (to add to
the `.vimrc`):

```
vmap ,i <Esc>l,bv,e
omap ,i :normal v,i<CR>
```

As you can see we make a use of the `,b` and `,e` motions defined by the plugin.

The first definition allow to type `,i` when we are in visual mode and it will
select the current "inner camelCase word". *(The `l` motion is a workaround to always get the word the cursor is on. Otherwise we get the previous one when the cursor is on the first letter of a word)*

The second definition uses the first
one to let operators like `d` or `c` work with `,i`

After we installed the plugin and added the definitions to our `.vimrc`
we can do what you wanted. For example if I take this example:

```
DefaultHandlerWord
```

If my cursor is on the letter `n` of `Handler` I can use:

- `,e` to go to the last letter of `Handler`
- `,b` to go to the first letter of `Handler`
- `,w` to go to the first letter of `Word`
- `d,i` to delete `Handler` and get only `DefaultWord`
- `c,i` to delete `Hanlder` and get a chance to replace it by another word

Comment: Also for questions about Vim ones might be interested by the [dedicated stack exchange site](http://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same question, and resolved it with this .vimrc mapping:

```
nmap W /[A-Z]<CR>
```

Of course you can include numbers in the range if you want but instead of regular words via w, you can now "search forward for next capital letter" with W.  You many want to turn off highlight search in this case though.

Comment: This won't be a camel-case search.  It'll search just fine for the first segment, but the last segment will search clear to the next uppercase letter, even lines away.  Perhaps you wanted a "search to non-lowercase" instead?  (Include the number later).