# Moving to Words in CamelCase and Separated by Underscore in Vim

Tags: vim

I would like a single key binding to move through both CamelCase words and words separated by underscores--basically an improvement on this [Vim tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Moving_through_camel_case_words). Anyone up for the challenge?

For example (`|` is the cursor):

pressing `<C-Right>` on `|someVariable` should bring the cursor to `some|Variable`

pressing `<C-Right>` on `|some_variable` should bring the cursor to `some_|variable`

Comment: This here probably answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1279462

Comment: What did you try already? How did it fail?

Comment: @gits I was hoping to not have to install a plugin, although I suppose  it would work.

Comment: @romainl I tried modifying the regex from the Vim tip, but I couldn't understand it well enough to make it work.